# How can I take a column without changing the value of a column when I use groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my gravity3:

| country_o | regime_o | country_d | regime_d | trade_o | trade_d | col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 1 | Turkey | 0 | 1231231 | 4929394 | 0 |

my code:

```
 gravity3 = gravity2.groupby(["country_d", "year", "regime_o"]).agg({"tradeflow_imf_d":"sum"})
```

I want to include "col" without changing it.  For a given year and country it should give one single value.

Comment: IIUC that's not possible. The moment you groupby and aggregate your data, you need to define how to aggregate the data you want to include.

Comment: If I use agg("col":"min")  given that col is only a binary variable. Would not I get a 1 or 0 for each year and country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `groupby` defines what make a group. In your case, a group is any rows that share the same `country_d`, `year`, and `regime_o` values. Your request  only make sense if there is only 1 `col` value for the whole group. Because when you have 2 or more `col` values per group, which one will you pick?

Assuming that there's only 1 `col` per group and you want to select that, there are a few options you can choose from:

```py
# 1. include it in the groupby function
gravity2.groupby(["country_d", "year", "regime_o", "col"])...

# 2. aggregate it with mean (numeric only), first or last
# Because all `col` in a group are identical, all three
# aggregate function will return the same value
(
    gravity2.groupby(["country_d", "year", "regime_o"])
    .agg({"tradeflow_imf_d":"sum", "col": "first"})
)
```

Comment: Many thanks, it perfectly works!